# How get the number of records found by a search query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a search engine for my website and I wanted to add the number of results found, I looked for functions doing that, but all what I found wasn't in PDO. So I decided to run the query twice but I'm not sure if it's possible. Is there a better way to count the results in PDO? Else, Is it safe to run the same query twice? Thank you!

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['tab']))
        {
            if($_GET['tab'] == 'all')
            {
                $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR details LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR link LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' LIMIT 20');
            }
            else if($_GET['tab'] == 'products')
            {
                $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM search WHERE  (type = \'products\') AND (title LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR details LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR link LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\') LIMIT 20');
            }
            else if($_GET['tab'] == 'blogpost')
            {
                $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM search WHERE (type = \'blogpost\') AND (title LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR details LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR link LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\') LIMIT 20');
            }
            else if($_GET['tab'] == 'forumthread')
            {
                $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM search WHERE (type = \'forumthread\') AND (title LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR details LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\' OR link LIKE \'%'.$_GET['searchquery'].'%\') LIMIT 20');
            }
    ?>

        <div id="resultsconainter">
            <div id="tabsconatiner">

            </div>
        <?php
            else
            {
                echo '<p>Sorry, this section is not available!</p>';
            }
                if(isset($query))
                {
                    for($i=0; $i<100;  $i++)
                    {
                        if($result = $query->fetch())
                        {
                            $_GET['searchquery'] = rawurlencode($_GET['searchquery']);
                            $result = preg_replace("#\\b(" . $_GET['searchquery'] . ")\\b#i", "<b>$1</b>", $result);
                            echo '<div class="result">
                            <a class="title" href="/qsoft/'.$result['link'].'">'.$result['title'].'</a>
                            <span class="link">
                                <span class="beforelink" style="font-size:1.1em;font-size:1.3vw;position:relative;top:1px;padding-right:1px;">&#8227;</span>
                                localhost/QSoft/'.$result['link'].'
                            </span>
                            <span class="details">'.$result['details'].'</span>
                            </div>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if($i==0)
                            {
                                echo '<p>Sorry, no resluts found here for : &nbsp;<b>'.$_GET['searchquery'].'</b></p>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo'<p>Missing tab informations, please retry</p>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for the search engine you should run two queries:

- one to get the actual search results. Note that **you should always limit the number of selected rows right in the SQL query**, using LIMIT operator
- one to get the number of rows matching the search criteria. **This query should return no actual rows** but just a single number.

For mysql, however, you can use a trick

For the first query, add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword right after `SELECT`:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM search ... LIMIT 20');
```

while for the second just run this simple code

```
$count = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Wait, if I do this, the results number would be after showing the results, am I right?

Comment: you can show any data wherever you want. before or after or instead results

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you use something like this `$result = $sth->fetchAll();` to get all the records form your query, you can do `count($result)` to have number of records returned. So no need for 1 queries.

For a more accurate answer, it's better to provide us part of your code, so we can assist you.

Answer (score -2):

Ok so here is what I did, I it not very clean but it works:

```
if(isset($query))
                {
                    $didgetcount = false;
                    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
                    {
                        if($result = $query->fetch())
                        {
                            $_GET['searchquery'] = rawurlencode($_GET['searchquery']);
                            $result = preg_replace("#\\b(" . $_GET['searchquery'] . ")\\b#i", "<b>$1</b>", $result);
                            echo '<div class="result">
                            <a class="title" href="/qsoft/'.$result['link'].'">'.$result['title'].'</a>
                            <span class="link">
                                <span class="beforelink" style="font-size:1.1em;font-size:1.3vw;position:relative;top:1px;padding-right:1px;">&#8227;</span>
                                localhost/QSoft/'.$result['link'].'
                            </span>
                            <span class="details">'.$result['details'].'</span>
                            </div>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if($i==0)
                            {
                                echo '<p>Sorry, no resluts found here for : &nbsp;<b>'.$_GET['searchquery'].'</b></p>';
                                echo '<script> document.getElementById("resultsnumber").innerText = 0;</script>';
                                $didgetcount = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if($didgetcount == false)
                                {
                                    echo '<script>
                                                function writeresults(n)
                                                {
                                                    document.getElementById("resultsnumber").innerText = n;
                                                }
                                                writeresults('.$i.');
                                          </script>';
                                    $didgetcount = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo'<p>Missing tab informations, please retry</p>';
            }
```

Comment: what do you think? Is there something to fix? It worked properly for me.